# Blazor Identity Scaffolding with the _Host.cshtml file as Layout

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I created a Blazor Application with Authentication (Individual User Accounts). Everything works fine as it is, but I want to customize the - let's say - login page. Also, the auto-generated layout annoys me. So I scaffolded the login using Add -> New Scaffolded Item -> Identity -> Selected Login and OK. For the Layout File I chose _Host.cshtml, the one that the rest of my Blazor application uses as well. If I now select "login" in my webpage, I get this Error:

`InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'BlazorIdentityTest.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'BlazorIdentityTest.Pages.Pages__Host'.`

So my question is: How do I get around this error? Is it even possible to use this Layout file with the Identity system? If not, is there another way to use the Blazor layout instead of the default from the Identity System?

I'm using the .Net Core 3.1.100 SDK.

Comment: You get any solution for this ?

Comment: Sadly no. I tried building the login page myself with blazor, but as it turns out, using HttpContext with a blazor component is not really possible. I read somewhere, that you could create a controller which handles the authentication and then just call it from the blazor view using POST. But I chose to wait until the ASP.NET Core team has figured out a way to implement the identity system better with blazor.